# React - Toggle Modal on/off and populate based on card specific data

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, popup

I have cards set up that have specific data in each of them (job number, title, etc.) and I tried to add a pop up modal that can be used to see more details about the job. If you click the "View Details" button, a modal should pop up that has more details on the specific card.

However, when doing this, react renders all of the cards at once because there is only one toggleModal function that gets triggered by each button. I would like for the data show to be from that specific card that you pressed the button.

I've been messing around for a while trying new things, and I'm pretty new to react.

All pop ups render when only one should render.

Need some way to check which card was clicked and only render that specific pop up. Here is the code:

```js
function ActiveJobs() {
  const [cards] = React.useState([
    {
      title: "Customer Name: Smith, James",
      jobnum: "Job Number: 1829",
      crewnum: "Crew: 0/2",
      address: "1825 Olive Ave",
    },
    {
      title: "Customer Name: Cherry, John",
      jobnum: "Job Number: 8421",
      crewnum: "Crew: 0/3",
      address: "256 Milwood Sq",
    },
    {
      title: "Customer Name: Rudd, Paul",
      jobnum: "Job Number: 0281",
      crewnum: "Crew: 0/4",
      address: "4272 Lowes Island Blvd",
    },
    {
      title: "Customer Name: Robbie, Margot",
      jobnum: "Job Number: 2516",
      crewnum: "Crew: 0/3",
      address: "265 Atlas Lane",
    },
    {
      title: "Customer Name: Bond, James",
      jobnum: "Job Number: 0420",
      crewnum: "Crew: 0/5",
      address: "1418 10th Ave",
    },
    {
      title: "Customer Name: Jordan, Micheal",
      jobnum: "Job Number: 7617",
      crewnum: "Crew: 0/10",
      address: "180 Goat Dr",
    },
  ]);

  const [modal, setModal] = React.useState(false);

  const toggleModal = () => {
    setModal(!modal);
  };

  if (modal) {
    document.body.classList.add("active-modal");
  } else {
    document.body.classList.remove("active-modal");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <section>
        <div className="container">
          <h1>All Active Jobs</h1>
          <div className="cards">
            {cards.map((card, i) => (
              <div key={i} className="card">
                <h3>{card.title}</h3>
                <p>{card.jobnum}</p>
                <p>{card.crewnum}</p>
                <p>{card.address}</p>
                <button className="cardbtn" onClick={toggleModal}>
                  View Details
                </button>
                <button className="cardbtn">Assign Crew</button>
                {modal && (
                  <div className="modal">
                    <div onClick={toggleModal} className="overlay"></div>
                    <div className="modal-content">
                      <h2>Job Details</h2>
                      <p>{card.title}</p>
                      <p>{card.jobnum}</p>
                      <p>{card.crewnum}</p>
                      <p>{card.address}</p>
                      <button className="close-modal" onClick={toggleModal}>
                        CLOSE
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                )}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <ActiveJobs />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store an id or index in the modal variable to keep track of which modal should be displayed.

```
const [modal, setModal] = useState({
  index: null,
  active: false,
});
```

I would also create another function to show the modal when the View Details button is clicked, otherwise if a modal is already open, clicking on the View Details button will hide it if you call the toggleModal function when clicking on the button.

```
const toggleModal = () => {
  setModal((prevModal) => ({
    ...prevModal,
    active: !prevModal.active,
  }));
};

const showDetails = (index) => {
  setModal((prevModal) => ({
      index,
      active: true,
    }));
};

<button className="cardbtn" onClick={() => showDetails(i}>
  View Details
 </button>
```

I would also recommend putting the if/else statement for updating the body classes inside a useEffect hook since you are updating the document which is outside of the React component. If you are unfamiliar with useEffect, these links could be helpful: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-useeffect-absolute-beginners/, https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_useeffect.asp, https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (modal.active) {
    document.body.classList.add("active-modal");
  } else {
    document.body.classList.remove("active-modal");
  }
}, [modal.active])
```

So, all together it would look like this:

```
import { useState } from "react";
    import "./ActiveJobs.css";

    export default function ActiveJobs() {
  const [cards] = useState([
    {
      title: "Customer Name: Smith, James",
      jobnum: "Job Number: 1829",
      crewnum: "Crew: 0/2",
      address: "1825 Olive Ave",
    },
    {
      title: "Customer Name: Cherry, John",
      jobnum: "Job Number: 8421",
      crewnum: "Crew: 0/3",
      address: "256 Milwood Sq",
    },
    {
      title: "Customer Name: Rudd, Paul",
      jobnum: "Job Number: 0281",
      crewnum: "Crew: 0/4",
      address: "4272 Lowes Island Blvd",
    },
    {
      title: "Customer Name: Robbie, Margot",
      jobnum: "Job Number: 2516",
      crewnum: "Crew: 0/3",
      address: "265 Atlas Lane",
    },
    {
      title: "Customer Name: Bond, James",
      jobnum: "Job Number: 0420",
      crewnum: "Crew: 0/5",
      address: "1418 10th Ave",
    },
    {
      title: "Customer Name: Jordan, Micheal",
      jobnum: "Job Number: 7617",
      crewnum: "Crew: 0/10",
      address: "180 Goat Dr",
    },
  ]);

  const [modal, setModal] = useState({
    index: null,
    active: false,
  });

  const showDetails = (index) => {
    setModal((prevModal) => ({
      index,
      active: true,
    }));
  };

  const toggleModal = () => {
    setModal((prevModal) => ({
      ...prevModal,
      active: !prevModal.active,
    }));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (modal.active) {
      document.body.classList.add("active-modal");
    } else {
      document.body.classList.remove("active-modal");
    }
  }, [modal.active])

  return (
    <div>
      <section>
        <div className="container">
          <h1>All Active Jobs</h1>
          <div className="cards">
            {cards.map((card, i) => (
              <div key={i} className="card">
                <h3>{card.title}</h3>
                <p>{card.jobnum}</p>
                <p>{card.crewnum}</p>
                <p>{card.address}</p>
                <button className="cardbtn" onClick={() => showDetails(i)}>
                  View Details
                </button>
                <button className="cardbtn">Assign Crew</button>
                {modal.active && modal.index === i && (
                  <div className="modal">
                    <div onClick={toggleModal} className="overlay"></div>
                    <div className="modal-content">
                      <h2>Job Details</h2>
                      <p>{card.title}</p>
                      <p>{card.jobnum}</p>
                      <p>{card.crewnum}</p>
                      <p>{card.address}</p>
                      <button className="close-modal" onClick={toggleModal}>
                        CLOSE
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                )}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    );
   }
```